# Change Table Row color based on condition in React

Tags: reactjs, colors, row

I want to change table row color based on condition .

My code :

```
 <TableBody>
                {
                this.props.result.alpha.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row,i) =>(

                  <TableRow  key={i} >

                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row"  >
                     <Typography variant="h4"> {row.a} </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4">{row.b}</Typography>  </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"> {row.c} </Typography> </TableCell>

                  </TableRow>

                ))}
 </TableBody>
```

Now i want to check if the value of key==null then color of row should be some color1 or else color2

i.e., Something like this.

if(row.c==null) then rowcolor= color1;

else rowcolor= color2;

How to do this in react ?

Answer (score -1):

Nt: Your question is rather vague and need more clarification.

I suppose you want to set a class based on a condition, yeah?

You can use a tarnary operator to set a class name based on your condition.

First you need to create two classes. One for the positive condition and the other for the contrary.

Then do something like

```js
 <TableBody>
                {
                this.props.result.alpha.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row,i) =>(

                  <TableRow  key={i}  >

                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row"  >
                     <Typography variant="h4"> {row.a} </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4">{row.b}</Typography>  </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"  style={row.c === null ? blue : pink > {row.c} </Typography> </TableCell>

                  </TableRow>

                ))}
 </TableBody>

const pink = {
backgroundColor: 'pink'
}

const blue ={
backgroundColor: 'blue'
}
```

#### Edit

In regards to the clarification made by the OP, I have changed from className to style.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually i want to check whether row.c is null or not in every iteration. If it is null then the color of row should be blue or else pink.

Comment: how does  style={row.c === null ? 'blue' : 'pink'  work?? if the {} is not closed?

Comment: I know how react works, just puzzled as HOW 
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"  style={row.c === null ? blue : pink > {row.c} </Typography> </TableCell>
Can work since 
style={row.c === null ? blue : pink
is not a closed object but ok
Downvoting your answer as it is clearly broken code

Comment: In other words:
                 <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"  style={row.c === null ? blue : pink > {row.c} </Typography> </TableCell>
Has 2 { and one } hope you understand how that works